# Group timestamp column by year

Tags: sql, timestamp

I want to group the `timestamp` column by year. I am working with two columns. one with 3 factor levels (YES, NO AND N/A) and a timestamp column in the form of (YYYY-MM-DD H:M:S).

I want to get the frequency of the 3 factor levels per year. So I need to extract the year from the timestamp column but iI cant figure it out.

I am working with a version of `Rstudio` where you cant download package from online but have to work with the ones already installed. No access to SSIS package, no `datepart` function available. Also tried using the year function for the code below but I keep getting error.

```
SELECT  Housing, year('datetime')
FROM tablex
GROUP BY year('datetime')
```

Only package I do have available are `lubridate` and `strptime` function.
PS: the timestamp is stored as a factor when try and changing to numeric or characters i get N/A everywhere. Please help!

Comment: `Housing` is looking for a aggregate function xD

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Why are you passing a string constant to a function named `year()`? Shouldn't you pass a proper timestamp or date value?

Comment: Remove the apostrophe from the datetime field, otherwise sql will think it's a string, should be...

`SELECT  Housing, year(datetime)` 
`FROM tablex` 
`GROUP BY Housing`